# Nvidia proprietary drivers wrong screen resolution

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, display-resolution

(Warning: english isn't my native language)

Hi, I'm currently using a DIV to VGA adapter with my NVIDIA GTX 950 graphic card, but when I choose to use the proprietary drivers I can't set my screen resolution to 1920x1080, even with xrandr (throws a BadMatch error).

I'm 'googling' this for hours but still no success. Someone knows how to fix this?

SO: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: which driver version are you using?

Comment: I tried with the default proprietary driver from Ubuntu 18.04, version 390 I think